# Include XQuery result through include in MarkLogic

Tags: nosql, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Is any way we can include XQuery result in an XML document as we include other document or XPath.

For example:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude";

xdmp:document-insert("/test1.xml", <document>
  <p>This is a sample document.</p>
  <xi:include href="test2.xml"/> 
</document>);

xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace xinc="http://marklogic.com/xinclude" at "/MarkLogic/xinclude/xinclude.xqy"; 

xinc:node-expand(fn:doc("/test1.xml"))
```

Can This be done as below:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude";

xdmp:document-insert("/test1.xml", <document>
  <p>This is a sample document.</p>
  <xi:include href="test2.xqy?var1=Hello&var2=world/> 
</document>);

xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace xinc="http://marklogic.com/xinclude" at "/MarkLogic/xinclude/xinclude.xqy"; 

xinc:node-expand(fn:doc("/test1.xml"))
```

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Within XQuery, an XML literal can include the result of an inline expression.

Such expressions can include a call to `xdmp:invoke()`.

As a result, code similar the following untested example should work (replacing the MarkLogic 9 syntax for the external variables map with the MarkLogic 8 equivalent if you're on MarkLogic 8):

```
let $doc :=
    <document>
        <p>This is a sample document.</p>
        {xdmp:invoke("test2.xqy",
            map:entry("var1","Hello")
            => map:with("var2", "world")
            )}
    </document>
return (
    xdmp:document-insert("/test1.xml", $doc),
    $doc
    )
```

By the way, it's more efficient to return the inserted document from the same transaction than to read the document in a separate transaction.  If the insertion fails, the transaction won't return the document, so reading in a separate transaction provides no greater assurance.

Hoping that helps,